# Copy artifact in Artifactory to a remote repository

Tags: maven-2, artifactory

I have the following setup:

- Development server for continuous build with Hudson, Maven and Artifactory up and running.
- I am able to build an artifact by Maven, and let Hudson deploy it to Artifactory.

However, I would like to do the following:

1. Select an artifact in Artifactory on the local build server.
2. Deploy that artifact to a remote repository without doing a new build.

The reason I want to do that is, that the first server is a development server where new artifacts are changed at will. The other server / repository is the public visible server for all artefacts of the company.

I know that I am able to create a second build job, but that would be a duplication, and Hudson is only able to manage one Artifactory repository at one time. I could deploy that artifact by hand to a different URL, but this is error prune and I need a login on the build server and have to use the shell to do that.

Has anyone an idea how to finally reach the goal?

Comment: Are you wanting to select different artifacts manually? Or, are you looking for something, to add to your build, that deploys an artifact to multiple repositories automatically?

Comment: I have added an explanation why we need the second scenario. So we want to build athe artifacts on one server, but deplay them to a different one without rebuilding them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly it looks like a good scenario for [User Plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins). It should be straightforward, you select the needed artifacts using the searches object, and then execute REST PUT call to put them on the remote server.

Comment: Nice idea, didn't knew that. I will give it a try (but will need some time to do that).

Answer (score 1):

The Maven Stage plugin seems to support this case: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-stage-plugin/usage.html

but I'm not sure if it works correctly. I'm working on it currently, so if it doesn't work perhapse I will find time to correct it.